# Why is this question considered opinion-based?

Tags: discussion

What are the differences between those questions?

[Why is FIFA/UEFA against temporary suspensions?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/14026/why-is-fifa-uefa-against-temporary-suspensions) (considered opinion-based)

[Why is FIFA against adding instant replay to the game?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/179/why-is-fifa-against-adding-instant-replay-to-the-game) (good and also protected question - **with 60 upvotes is the second most upvoted question**)

It is not clear to me how is it possible those differences

Answer (score 3):

My take: in general, questions of the form "Why does <governing body for sport> not implement <some feature>?" are very likely to be questions to which we can't get anything other than an opinion-based answer, as the governing body hasn't made any comment on the vast number of suggestions that are made to "improve" a sport; as such, the default position would be to close such questions.

Instant replay in football is a special case, as there has been extensive media coverage of the issue and (as corsiKa's answer shows) even comments on the matter from football's governing body. I appreciate this is a chicken-and-egg problem in that nobody's going to be able to add official comments on the matter if we close the question, but I think that's possibly better than leaving them open and getting a load of low-quality answers.

As an aside, I wouldn't particularly regard number of upvotes as an indicator of a good question - for a low traffic site like ours, that much more means "made it onto the network Hot Questions list" than anything else. Similarly, protection means "this question has had a number of bad answers" and says nothing about the quality of the question itself.

Comment: Also for this case, it was one of the first questions this site ever had.

Comment: @ᴍᴀsᴛᴇʀᴍɪɴᴅ_ᴇᴅ Are the rules changed from that period?

Comment: @Ale I have no idea, but I assume so as the site has definitely evolved since. I wasn't a member at the time, so I can't speak to why that had been allowed (probably to have content for content's sake).